# How to build jar Library for openconnect client? (no configure file)

Tags: java, compilation

I want to build a jar-library for the openconnect client. But I couldn't find the configure-file there is only a configure.ac file that seems to include the code for the configure file. The content of the readme-file couldn't help me:

```
Description:

This directory contains a JNI interface layer for libopenconnect, and a
demo program to show how it can be used.

Build instructions:

From the top level, run:

./configure --with-java
make
cd java
ant
sudo java -Djava.library.path=../.libs -jar dist/example.jar     <server_ip>

If ocproxy[1] is installed somewhere in your $PATH, this can be run as a
non-root user and it should be pingable from across the VPN.

Test/demo code is in src/com/example/
OpenConnect wrapper library is in src/org/infradead/libopenconnect/

[1] http://repo.or.cz/w/ocproxy.git
```

ant worked but ./configure didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: to start, this is a java problem, not a c problem. Please remove the 'c' tag.

Comment: To have us be any help, post the actual output from `./configure --with-java`  otherwise we would only be guessing.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't explain it right. There is no configure file but a configure.ac file. The configure.ac contains a if condition with the parameter `with-java` . So I started it and I get the following error: `./configure.ac: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token 'openconnect,'
./configure.ac: line 1: AC_INIT(openconnect, 7.06)`